# Where do Fuerte deb files get installed?

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, deb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where are the contents of ROS Fuerte deb packages unpacked to?

I am trying to get ROS Fuerte running on an embedded x86 Linux distribution. For Diamondback and Electric I was able to simply copy `/opt/ros/{diamondback,electric}/` over to my target, set some Python environment variables, and everything "Just Worked". With Fuerte I have seen mailing list messages suggesting that the deb install files are moving some of the ROS files to locations other than `/opt/ros/fuerte/` but I can't seem to find exactly which files those are or where they are expected to be installed.

What I am really looking for is something similar to what I can find at [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/vim), and when I click on [list of files](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/amd64/vim/filelist) it shows me where all of the package contents are installed on the system. That would allow me to manually (or via a script) find all the files I need and copy them over to the target.

I tried looking through the [Fuerte SIG](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Planning) notes but couldn't find the answer there. If there is a page that has this discussion a link would be appreciated so I can use Google better in the future. Thanks.

*Update:*

I had to copy `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/rospkg` and `/usr/bin/rosversion` into a directory on my target OS `$PATH`. Also, I had to have parts of `/usr/lib/python2.6/`, especially `/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload`, copied onto my target OS with `$PYTHONPATH` set to add those directories. Note that it is likely that not all the files in those directories are required, but I haven't gone through and parsed out the necessary subset, so this won't be as efficient space-wise as it could be.

After that I could run `roscore` (`roslaunch`) although I get a few warnings that seem safe to ignore since everything is connecting just fine over the network. Thanks for the answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32930/where-do-fuerte-deb-files-get-installed?/) by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4347 on 2012-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that the files are still in the /opt/ros prefix.

This [REP 122](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0122.html) details the new filesystem hierarchy.

I believe that the intent of this new layout is to allow users to install directly into the /usr prefix if desired.  Then all of the ROS files will map into /usr/bin, /usr/etc, /usr/lib, and so forth.

While it is possible to use a different prefix, as far as I know, files are still placed in the /opt/ros/fuerte prefix by default.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

mjcarroll's answer is correct with respect to where the files are.

to answer your question re: packages.ubuntu.com-style listings, you just have to run:

```
dpkg -L ros-fuerte-stack-name
```

e.g.

```
dpkg -L ros-fuerte-ros
```

This will enumerate all of the installed files for a given deb.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-04-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2012-04-29**:
Thanks @kwc, I didn't know about the -L flag for dpkg.